# Why this code report a Gas estimation failed error in remix?

Tags: solidity, gas

Both two functions(callReplAuction and testswapToPFIL) report Gas estimation failed error in the remix!

You could deploy this code in any blockchain network and could use any address in the function address parameter. Address parameter is not important.

[image]

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
    
    interface IRepl {
        function buy(uint _amount, uint _id) external;
        function auctionInfo() external view returns (uint, uint, uint, uint, uint);
    }
    
    interface IUniswapSwapHelper {
        function swapToPFIL(uint payAmount, uint minAmount, uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96) external payable returns(uint);
    }
    
    contract CallReplAuction {
        receive() external payable {}
    
        
        function callReplAuction(address replAuction) external {
             (,,,,uint auctionId) = IRepl(replAuction).auctionInfo();
             IRepl(replAuction).buy(100, auctionId);
        }
    
        function testswapToPFIL(address uniswapHelper) external payable returns (uint) {
            return IUniswapSwapHelper(uniswapHelper).swapToPFIL(msg.value, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you said is correct.

*You could deploy this code in any blockchain network and could use any address in the function address parameter. The address parameter is not important.*

You are wrapping the address parameter inside an interface which means the address parameter must be contract and must have the functions provided in the interface.

Pass the correct addresses and it should work.

Comment: the address is not important, before the transaction is sent to the network, the error is emitted. And I entered the right address, the same result.

Comment: I just told you why the address is important. The transaction will never go through if you don't understand what I am saying. because Remix tries to simulate sending the actual transaction and it will tell you why the call is gonna fail. It clearly says in the error, that "Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract". If you still wanna check, then click on the "send transaction" button and see why the tx fails. Also do give a read to some articles explaining "What are interfaces?"

Comment: could you try in this rpc: https://api.calibration.node.glif.io/rpc/v1 and this address: 0x75300F6C5620b4161Fc0729b83cFFE72BdDE62C4 and call the function: callReplAuction? I have make a tx here: https://calibration.filfox.info/en/tx/0x20b1d3a6b8a502cb2bc72f2181f2dfb05de32346e7d60f6aa96ed1e749d91031?t=1

Comment: 0x75300F6C5620b4161Fc0729b83cFFE72BdDE62C4 is the contract IRepl's address

Comment: I got the answer. there is not a contract in the address, or the address doesn't have the function, and the function has any logic error, which will cause the remix to throw the gas estimation failed.

Comment: and remix will fork the chain network state to local, try to run the logic in the local network first.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I said. The address you provide inside the interface needs to be a  contract and contain the function that you are trying to call. Whether it's a local network or any testnet, the story is same